# cannot resolve spring message code using messageSource

Tags: java, spring, localization, resourcebundle

I am trying to hook up a messageSource in spring to use for my application. Its not working, gives this error:

> org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'validation_required' for locale 'en'.

my **applicationContext.xml** contains this def for messageSource:

```
   <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:messages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

my messages properties file lives in:

```
/WEB-INF/classes/messages/messages_en_US.properties
```

Finally, the call i made that generates the error is:

```
String message = messageSource.getMessage("validation_required", null, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Can anyone help me at this hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the way you have defined the resource bundle and the locale you are specifying (They doesn't match with the resource bundle's [search order](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). Either rename your bundle to "messages_en.properties" or invoke the "getMessage(...)" with new Locale("en","US"). I prefer the first option.

Comment: Link is now broken

Answer (score 5):

It seems like your path is not correct.
since you have your bundle under /WEB-INF/classes/messages/messages_en_US.properties, your basename setting should look like: classpath:messages/messages (basename in this case means path and properties file prefix).

Answer (score 3):

I use following bean and it is working fine without specifying the path to the file:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" abstract="false"
      scope="singleton" lazy-init="default">
    <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
</bean>
```

Although the files I use are simply called "messages_en.properties" and "messages_es.properties" well you get the idea.

When you call

```
    messageSource.getMessage("validation_required", null, null);
```

do you get an exception? Try to use this file name messages_en.properties or messages_us_en.properties

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
look at the comment for getting the string

```
package yours;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;

/**
 *  
 * Permet la recuperation des String du LocaleContextHolder hors des jsp 
 * Les langues sont placées dans main/ressources/messagesSources.properties 
 * 
 * Example : new MSG("recuperation_name_invalid").value()
 * 
 */
@Configurable
public class MSG
{

    private String key;

    @Resource(name = "messageSource")
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    public MSG(String key)
    {
        super();
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String value()
    {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();

        return messageSource.getMessage(key, new Object[0], locale);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return value();
    }


}
```

Comment: This is very inefficient, instantiating the whole MSG object everytime you need a string (with the @Resource part)