# External properties file as spring MessageSource not working

Tags: java, spring

Consider below code:

```
<bean id="busmessageSource" 
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:bundles/resource</value>
            <value>classpath:bundles/override</value>
            <value>file:/C:/mmt/override</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="100" />
</bean>
```

Here properties from `bundles/resource` and `bundles/override` get fetched when I call `busmessageSource.getMessage("anykey", null, null)`

but it fails when I try to fetch values for properties in `C:/mmt/override`

1. What is correct way of configuring messagesource with external file from the disk.
2. Also I want `file:/C:/mmt/override` to override values in `classpath:bundles/override` if any with the same key exist. How do I override properties from an external file outside of my war folder?

Answer (score 9):

**1.)** I have these 3 ways:

- One solution is to add your "`C:/mmt/`" folder to your resource classpath.
- This is another way that may help you [ResourceBundle not found for MessageSource when placed inside a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150869/resourcebundle-not-found-for-messagesource-when-placed-inside-a-folder)
- Use this code: (Worked for me)

```xml
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename">
        <beans:value>file:/path/to/messages</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

**Note1**: You **must** use the } `file:` prefix and the `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` class.

**Note2**: Do **not** put the ".properties" extension.

**2.)** You override previous values when you load a new properties file with same property names (keys). You must ensure that you fetch last the properties file you want to use.

Comment: If you want to RELOAD a properties file during a program execution you can check this post http://learningviacode.blogspot.com/2012/07/reloadable-messagesources.html

Comment: What did the trick for me was indeed removing the ".properties" at the end and adding "file:" at the start. Thank you for pointing that in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
<bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:bundles/resource</value>
            <value>classpath:bundles/override</value>
            <value>file:C:/mmt/override</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

About message resource keep note:

1. A plain path will be relative to the current application context.
2. A "classpath:" URL will be treated as classpath resource.
3. A "file:" URL will load from an absolute file system path.
4. Any other URL, such as "http:", is possible too.

Comment: Do you know where "a plain path" be related to? It cannot find the properties under the project folder or the same folder of the java file.

Comment: Can you provide the folder structure you are using? I termed "plain path" from application context. The application context in web application is actually the directory which contains **WEB-INF**. For maven based project structure it is in **ProjectName/src/main/webapp/**. Suppose your file name is **application.properties** which resides in same directory as **WEB-INF**. Than the value should be **application**. If it is under **WEB-INF** than use **WEB-INF/application**. If still does not solve please feel free to comment again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar question (by the title of your question) and managed to instantiate Spring [ResourceBundleMessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) with `java.util.Properties`.

```
ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
messageSource.setCommonMessages(properties);
```

Kind of naive approach, but did the job for my unit testing.