# springMVC : No message found under code 'com.info.write.text' for locale 'en_US'

Tags: java, spring, jsp, io

While reading properties file from folder `com.resources` I got following error

`javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'com.info.write.text' for locale 'en_US'.`

I am not using `maven`. So, I understand that spring will not read the `resources` automatically.

I know how to write and read data from simple property file in java is simple task as, need to provide path using `FileReader` now the question is how I can provide path to properties file?

This is some relevant part of my `dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml`

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="message" />
    </bean>
```

here is data of property file i.e (`message.property`)

```
com.info.write.text=Greetings of the day
```

This is how I am trying to use data from property file as message

```
<p><spring:message code="com.info.write.text" /></p>
```

and the file structure to `message.properties` is

`src/com/resources/message.properties`

How to read properties file in spring without using `maven` or any `build tool`(directly) ?

Comment: Did you try renaming your `message.properties` file to `message_en.properties`?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150869/resourcebundle-not-found-for-messagesource-when-placed-inside-a-folder

Comment: @jlumietu this won't work the problem is spring don't know the path of properties file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use full name in `dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml`
like

```
<property name="basename" value="src/com/resources/message" />
```

or use `ClassPath` like

```
<property name="basename" value="classpath*:resources/message" />
```