# Spring Boot, Thymeleaf email template internationalization

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to change the language of the email template based on the users preferred language (ID of the preferred language is stored in the user table). When preparing the message I pass the Locale to the Context as shown below:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(user.getLanguage().getLocaleCode());
final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
ctx.setVariable("username", user.getUsername());
ctx.setVariable("address", user.getAddress());
```

When I log the result of the `getLocaleCode()` it returns the expected value, for example 'sr'. Inside my /resources/lang folder I have created messages_sr.properties file. But for some reason when I send the email it will always use the language in the default messages.properties.
Here is my configuration file:

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr;
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:lang/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

Inside the resources/lang folder I have:

- messages_en_US.properties
- messages_sr.properties

Based on the documentation and examples I was able to find I couldn't find the solution. Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to create the `messageSource` bean if you just want to put the translations in a subfolder. I use `spring.messages.basename=i18n/messages` on all my projects so they can be in `src/main/resources/i18n/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/11152674/3849555, please use `classpath*:lang/messages` instead.