# Reading properties file in Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring

spring.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">  

  <bean id="meassageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="resource\message">  
    </property>
  </bean>

 </beans>
```

Main.java class file

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        System.out.println(context.getMessage("emp", null, Locale.US));

    }

}
```

My properties file is in src/resource folder. File name is mesaage_en_US.properties.
I have also tried with different file names like message.property, message_en.property and with different locales like Locale.English, Locale.UK but no luck. 
I moved the property file to src folder but getting same exception. 
I am getting following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'emp' for locale 'en_US'.
    at org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource.getMessage(DelegatingMessageSource.java:65)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234)
    at org.beans.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Please help.

message_en_US.properties

```
emp=Hello Employee.
```

Comment: Sounds like your `ApplicationContext` is not auto-detecting your `MessageSource`. The bean name has a typo in it - is that how it is in your actual code?

Comment: Classpath properties should be separated by forward slashes so try resource/message.

Comment: @superEb There is no typo in actual code.

Comment: Have you tried what @samlewis suggested? Also, what if you get direct access to the `messageSource` bean by calling `ApplicationContext.getBean` and then calling `getMessage` against it?

Answer (score 6):

I like to use a [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) for that. [Here's a great tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/) to get you started.

Basically, you'll want to add:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />
```

to your spring xml config file, where "foo.properties" is a resource's absolute path within the class path.

Then you can inject them into fields like this:

```
@Value( "${jdbc.url}" )
private String jdbcUrl;
```

where "jdbc.url" is the reference name in your properties file.

Of course, the `@Value` won't work inside your `static void main`, but I really doubt `static void main` is where you want to use your properties anyway. You ought to be accessing them from a Spring Bean.

Comment: Right but its Test App.

Comment: Well, I would assert that when making a Spring test app, you should make it the way it should be made with Spring. So you should be testing that you can access the properties from Spring components, not directly from the application context. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822951/how-do-i-get-a-property-value-from-an-applicationcontext-object-not-using-an-a) has an answer that explains why you can't access property-placeholders from the context at runtime.

Comment: I have also tried by implementing MessageSourceAware interface in different bean. This is also not working.

Comment: While this is a good suggestion for configuration values, it does not address i18n, which is the main purpose of `MessageSource`.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
<property name="basename" value="message" />
```

with `message_en_US.properties` in the same folder as your `spring.xml`.

***EDIT** :* You have a typo in your *bean* name when defining the `MessageSource`. It's name should have been exactly `messageSource`. Because of that extra `a` in *meassageSource* `ApplicationContext` failed to load it.

Comment: @JitendraShukla Can you try moving the props file into `/src`?

Comment: @JitendraShukla You had a typo in your *bean* name.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is duplicated from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568230/cannot-resolve-spring-message-code-using-messagesource?rq=1) question. Basically, it has to do with a mismatch between your bundle and the locale specified in code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting message from `ApllicationContext` I am getting message from `MeassageSource` itself. I changed my spring.xml like this

```
<bean id="employee" class="org.bean.Employee" >
         <property name="id" value="1"/>
         <property name="name" value=""/>
         <property name="dept" value=""/>  
         <property name="messages" ref="messageSource"/>    
      </bean>
```

Now I am calling `messages.getMessage(this.messages.getMessage("emp", null, Locale.UK))` from `Employee` class. Its working.

Comment: Please check my update. You had incorrectly named the bean as *meassageSource* (notice the extra "a").

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced your error and found the problem. It has to do with Spring not finding the bundle. I think you should be getting a warning before the exception with the following message:

```
WARNING: ResourceBundle [resource\message] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name resource\message, locale en_US
```

This has been the hint. The problem is related to your project structure and how the bundles are searched when specifying setBasename property. Please take a look at [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setBasename%28java.lang.String%29).

Anyway I think you should put your bundles in the more standard location src/main/resources. If you follow this convention, your messageSource bean should be defined like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="message" />
</bean>
```

With this approach your example should produce the desired line:

> Hello Employee.

Comment: Right but if you get message from `ApplicationContext` then it will not work.

Comment: @JitendraShukla Sorry, but it is working. I've copied your code in a test project and the output is the expected one with no errors. I'm getting the message from the ApplicationContext.